# To what extent are lifestyle factors taken into account in medical testing?

Tags: pathology, health, epidemiology

A glance at any official health bodies advice will show that we are entreated to eat more healthily, take more exercise and reduce stress. Presumably, there is some reasonable evidence that these factors play a relatively significant role in disease formation and response (otherwise, one would presume they would not be within the remit of such organisations).

In what little opportunity I've had to read primary research on medical testing, however (I'm a statistician, not a biologist), I've not come across any attempt at stratification for these factors.

If one is, say, testing the response to a new medicine, presuming these factors will promote recovery in your test subjects, then the apparent efficacy of the medicine might be affected by the distribution of these "lifestyle" factors within your test and control groups.

Similarly, on the other side of the coin, if you are testing the response to a new health threat by epidemiological study, a quoted Odds Ratio of 1.2 might be quite radically different for individuals of different general health, yet (in the studies I've read) there seems to be simply a presumption that the control group and the test group will have a similar spread of lifestyles.

It certainly seems to be a relevant factor in some cases as individuals with a history of smoking are almost always controlled for in such epidemiological studies (especially related to lung conditions), but I have never come across similar treatment of individuals in high stress jobs, eating fewer than 5 fruit and veg per day, taking less than three hours exercise a week etc.

For large effects, these factors would probably be insignificant, but where the effect is small (say a slightly efficacious new treatment, or a low risk environmental contaminant), failure to take account of these factors could theoretically lead to the conclusion that the drug is a slight improvement on what we have, or the threat requires some moderate mitigation, when if fact the drug is virtually ineffective in people who are otherwise unhealthy, or the threat is actually zero to a healthy individual, which would be really important conclusions for public health.

My limited interaction with epidemiological studies was quite a few years ago now, so my question is, have things moved on to start controlling for these factors now we have a better idea of their impact, and more significantly, if they have, have any studies from the past been revised in the light of such controls? Also, does anyone know of any accessible studies on the impact of these factors on epidemiology in general?

To clarify in the light of the close reason. The question is a single one which can be simply answered by anyone involved in epidemiology or researching pathology. Do modern epidemiological studies of disease causal factors control for lifestyle factors, such as diet, obesity, exercise and stress? The answer I'm looking for would come from someone who is either involved in epidemiological research or reads a significant number of epidemiology papers and the would at it's simplest be " Yes, they do" or "No they don't". I'm not sure how much less broad it can get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is much better suited for Health.SE.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this question would be better suited to Health.SE. That site seems to be primarily about health questions, this question is about pathology and epidemiology research methods. Both tags exist here. If you're suggesting it's off topic simply because it relates to a health issue, then what questions could possibly fall under the epidemiology, health or pathology tags?

Comment: While it's true that the majority of questions on that site are personal medical questions, this is the kind of question they would welcome. Tags existed before Health.SE went into public beta.

Comment: A well intentioned consideration that another site might like to tackle the question, and voting to close as off-topic are two quite different things.

Comment: One of the close reasons is that 'this question is better suited to another SE site.' Not sure of the exact wording, but it is right there. I have nothing against this question; closing it would most likely lead to migration. I simply think there is a better site; both actions ate well-intentioned.

Comment: Most studies aren't large or sufficiently powerful enough to consider too many intervening factors. Only the largest trials could even attempt this. Most drug trials are basically as small as they can be, because they are 1) expensive, and 2) you are testing an unknown medication, so you don't want to unnecessarily expose patients to risks that might not yet be understood.

Comment: @anongoodnurse The answer to the question here https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3416/23094 seems to state quite specifically from a diamond mod that "Questions on medical science are on-topic here"

Comment: I disagree with the reopen, and the edit does not actually make it more specific. If you really want an answer as simple as that, it isn't really an appropriate question to ask here. The actual answer is obviously *it depends*: some studies will and some studies won't. Explaining all of the causes and reasons etc to make a solid answer is where it becomes too broad.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all. You seem to be saying that If I want a short answer the question isn't suitable for this site, but if I want a long answer it isn't suitable either. Also how does "Explaining all of the causes and reasons etc to make a solid answer" make the question too broad. To suggest that the choice to include lifestyle factor stratification in a control group is made considering reasons so vast and complex they couldn't even be summarised in an answer is ludicrous.

Comment: I worked (rather tangentially) on statistics for epidemiological studies a few years ago and in that limited experience absolutely none of the studies, no matter what size, stratified their control and test groups for any lifestyle factors, so if it's so "obvious" that some do, simply linking to one of them would have made a simple informative answer. The fact that, instead, everyone just seems to want to dodge the question has served as an answer in itself.

Comment: I wouldn't expect subjects to be stratified over lifestyle factors, since the number of groups would get prohibitively large as you add multiple dimensions of factors. However, demographic data is often included and analyzed, the whole fields of population health and epidemiology deal with these factors all the time, just not every factor in every study. Since you are a statistician, I am sure you are aware of the problems with testing too many factors simultaneously. You can design a better powered study if you focus on factors most expected to be of interest.

Comment: Testing two factors simultaneously is relatively simple, one only has to use an interactive term on one of the coefficients in a regression analysis, neither is dealing with multiple lifestyle factors complicated where the null hypothesis would be that lifestyle factors did not affect one's risk from the chemical concerned, a compound score for "general healthiness" can be used (and has been in the many studies correlating social status and health). Only if the null hypothesis is rejected would there be any interest in which lifestyle factor had most influence.

Comment: Additionally, as I requested in my previous comment, if " the whole fields of population health and epidemiology deal with these factors all the time". I really would be very grateful if you could point me in the direction of one of those many studies, that really was the point of me asking the question. You've twice asserted that at least some studies do take account of lifestyle factors sometimes and yet in my experience I've come across none that do, I'd really like to see an example of how it's done. Some links to the papers that have lead you to this conclusion would be much appreciated.